# How is ふう working here

Tags: words

> Interviewer: 政権は親米だったけど、国民は違っていたと。
>
> Interviewee: イランはその後、「アメリカというのは大悪魔だ」と言うようになるし、アメリカは「イランは世界のテロリストの親玉みたいな存在だ」という**ふう**に呼ぶんです。

It is an interview to a specialist.

How is ふう working there, or as what?  My assumption is that it is working as 風  for tendency/manner, but I am not so sure.

Comment: a bit more context would be nice. this sentence seems to be a follow up to prior sentence.

Comment: I did so. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. This usage corresponds with the following definition from [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A2%A8#SSDJJ)

> ふう ［1］ 【風】
> 一
> （ 名 ）
> ③ 方式。やり方。「どんな━に説得するか悩む」「私の発言をそんな━にとらないで下さい」

In this case, the "interviewee" uses ふう because 「イランは世界のテロリストの親玉みたいな存在だ」isn't a direct quotation of something a specific American official said about Iran on one particular occasion, but a kind of summary or paraphrase of the *way* in which American officials have typically talked about Iran since the revolution in 1979.